# WMP choppy file playback

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player

Recently i've been having issues with Windows Media Player like certain files playing choppy. This doesn't happen the first time i play the files but after a few playbacks

I have enough processing power and memory to be sure that's not the problem. I still took a look at my task manager and CPU was largely unused, only 3.5/8gig memory was being used

Other media players run the same files without any issue.

I suspect it might be a codec issue but i'm not quite sure. Is there a fix?

Comment: Since you tagged this with "mp3", I assume the problem is only with such files? Also, which version of WMP and Windows?

Comment: Yes, I've only yet experienced this with mp3 files. 
Windows 8 with wmp12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by disabling SRS audio enhancement.